# PHP: apply CSS to every second row

Tags: php, html, html-table, row

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set alternate row color for an iterated table in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570925/how-to-set-alternate-row-color-for-an-iterated-table-in-php)
>   [Using CSS :even and :odd pseudo-classes with list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items)

I have a html table populated with data from a mysql table.
I use the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<tr>";

echo "</tr>\n";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>";

foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";

echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

**Note:** I normally use PDO statments but for this example i use mysql.

The code generate the table correctly. The question is: I want to apply a CSS to every second row with the following `class=table_higlight`. How can I do this?

Comment: `:even` and `:odd` have a poor browser compatibility...

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  if ($i % 2 == 0 )
    echo '<tr class="even">';
  else
    echo '<tr class="odd">';

  foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";

  echo "</tr>\n";
  $i++
}
```

Comment: Why not just use css pseudo selectors eg. tr:odd or tr:even ?

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr".(++$ctr%2 == 0 ? ' class="table_highlight"' : '').">";

foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";

echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Why? foreach ($row as $cell) should list each column in the fetched row

Comment: No, the foreach is not useless. He is looping through all cells for the row. If you don't know the number of columns in the table, then you must loop through them all.